# TextView is not displaying on the top of the Google map

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, android-layout

```
TextView is not displaying on the top of the screen
```

Here is my code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rg_modes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_driving"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="@string/str_rb_driving" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_walking"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/str_rb_walking" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/tv_distance_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="distance" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/rg_modes" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `android:layout_below="@+id/distance"` as attribute `Fragment` xml as below...

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/rg_modes"
    android:layout_below="@+id/distance" />
```

Answer (score 0):

add `layout_below`

```
   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/rg_modes"
        android:layout_below="@id/distance" />
```

Answer (score 0):

put textview after mapview like this

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/rg_modes" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/distance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Distaceee" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that on `textview` you are assigning some text at run time properly other wise text view's data is not going to be displayed..

Any way, let's assume `textview`'s data is Coming properly at run time..

In this case on `<RadioGroup>` Replace this line

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

with below one

android:layout_below="@+id/distance"
```

& on `<fragment>` Give Height `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
android:layout_below="@id/distance"
```

to you fragment with id android:id="@+id/map"